# Quartz.Net cron trigger to schedule a job every month

Tags: c#, windows-services, quartz.net

I am trying to create a job with quartz.net which will run every 1 month

I am a little confused on how to implement this, can anyone advise on a solution

thanks

P.S. am using Quartz version 2.2.2.400

Edited:I made a daily trigger

```
job = JobBuilder.Create<Jobs>()
            .WithIdentity(Params.JobsKind.BlaBlaBla.ToString(), "group1")
            .Build();

        trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
            .WithIdentity("triggerBlaBlaBla", "group1")
            .WithDailyTimeIntervalSchedule(x => x.StartingDailyAt(Params.BlaBlaBLa)
                .WithIntervalInHours(24)
                .OnEveryDay())
            .Build();

        sched.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
```

now I need to be triggered monthly

Comment: Any effort? What have you tried?

Comment: Have you actually tried reading through the documentation? People say it helps.
http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/index.html

Comment: I edited the subject and i used the above code to trigger daily but i need to trigger monthly thanks in advance

Comment: Do you know about CronExpression? [http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-06]. Refer above link. So you can edit the cron expression directly whenever you want.

Comment: yes i read about it, but how to use it please any one can give me an example Mehul Vaghela

Comment: Take a look at http://www.cronmaker.com/. It is very useful.

Answer (score 10):

This is how I implemented my solution which is like yours,

Basically the **CronScheduleBuilder** class has a method **MonthlyOnDayAndHourAndMinute(day, hour, minute)** where you enter day, hour and minute for your job to run.

It works perfectly and is more human readable unless you are used to unix CRON jobs. Hope this helps.

```
            // define the job and tie it to  class
            IJobDetail job_tcs = JobBuilder.Create<DuesFeedbackJob>()
                .WithIdentity("job_tcs", "group1")
                .Build();
            // Trigger the job to run every 2nd of the month at 1 am
            ITrigger trigger_tcs = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                .WithIdentity("Run Infinitely every 2nd day of the month", "Monthly_Day_2")
                .StartNow()
                .WithSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.MonthlyOnDayAndHourAndMinute(2, 1, 0))
                .Build();

            // Tell quartz to schedule the job using our trigger
            Console.WriteLine("Scheduling " + job_tcs);
            scheduler.ScheduleJob(job_tcs, trigger_tcs);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is handled by making a cronExpression and adding it as a parameter to the CronScheduleBuilder.

The code will be like this:

```
static CronScheduleBuilder cronSchedule;

job = JobBuilder.Create<Jobs>()
            .WithIdentity(Params.JobsKind.BlaBlaBla.ToString(), "group1")
            .Build();

        CronExpression cexp = new CronExpression("0 50 10 1 * ?");
        cronSchedule = CronScheduleBuilder.CronSchedule(cexp);
        trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()

               .WithIdentity("triggerBlaBlaBla", "group1")
               .StartNow()
               .WithSchedule(cronSchedule)
               .Build();
        sched.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
```

Thnaks for who tried to help me

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CalendarIntervalSchedule,use RepeatFrequency is 1

```
trigger1 = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                        .ForJob(jobDetail1)
                        .StartAt(startDate)
                        .EndAt(endDate)
                        .WithIdentity(triggerName, "group1")
                        .WithCalendarIntervalSchedule(x => x.WithIntervalInMonths(RepeatFrequency))
                        .WithCalendarIntervalSchedule(x => x.WithMisfireHandlingInstructionFireAndProceed())
                        .Build();
```